# Accessing class variables with for loop

Tags: php, oop

I would like to access class variables with `for` loop, here is my simple class

```
class test{
    public $var1 = 1;
    public $var2 = 2;
    public $var3 = 3;
    public $var4 = 4;
}


$class = new test();
```

this is how i try to access variables with a loop

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++){
    echo $class->var.$i;
}
```

and i get error which says 
`Notice: Undefined property: test::$var in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 12`

Well it's not really a big error and i actualy get the value echoed but i still don't understand why do i get this error?

also if i do it this way everything works fine:

```
echo $class->var1;
```

Comment: try changing the class object name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually getting the value echoed, you're getting `$i` echoed.

`echo $class->var.$i;` is being interpreted as `echo ($class->var).($i);`.  Since `var` isn't a variable (hence the error), it becomes `echo ''.$i;`, so you get the value of `$i`.  It just so happens that `var1` has the value 1.  (Change `$var1` to something else, and you'll see what I mean)

To fix the issue, you can do this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++){
    $class->{'var'.$i}
}
```

The stuff inside the `{}` is calculated first, so the correct property is read.

Answer (score 6):

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++){
    $var = 'var' . $i;
    echo $class->$var;
}
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments, this will work in newer versions of PHP

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++){
    $class->{'var' . $i}
}
```

Comment: I think that `$class->{'var'.$i}` also works in later PHP versions.

Comment: @Xeoncross yes, $class->{'var'.$i} works at least back to 5.3. [This code on codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LVw7j0)

Comment: It's worth noting that `$class->{'var'.$i}()` is a different story. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The code isn't doing what you think. It's only echoing 1-4 because of your `$i` in the for loop. If you were to change the vars in the class, your output will still be 1-4.

The undefined property notices is the clue: it is trying to access the property `var`.

If you want to store data that is repetitive and/or associated, especially like in your example, it is usually more suitable to store as an array:

```
class test{
    public $vars;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->vars = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
    }
}

$obj = new test();

foreach($obj->vars as $var)
{
    echo $var;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The dot (.) operator is getting used by the echo rather than the member call to $class.

One of many solutions:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++){
     echo $class->{'var'.$i};
}
```

[live example here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LVw7j0)

Answer (score 0):

This already works fine on very recent PHP versions, but try this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++){
    $v = 'var'.$i;
    echo $class->$v;
}
```